# How to create a Docker production image using multi module gradle project with spring and angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, docker, gradle

I have a parent project  with 2 modules - spring and angular. ALl have the needed build.gradle, wrapper settings etc

```
rootProject.name = 'fullapp'

include 'serviceapp'
include 'uiapp'
```

gradlew clean build works ok from parent folder ...i.e. creates jar of UI etc. The gradle file of ui is

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id "com.moowork.node" version "1.2.0"
}
repositories.whenObjectAdded {
    if (it instanceof IvyArtifactRepository) {
        metadataSources {
            artifact()
        }
    }
}
node {
  version = '14.15.0'
  npmVersion = '6.14.8'
  download = true
}
jar.dependsOn 'npm_run_build'
jar {
  from 'dist/uiapp' into 'static'
}
```

I do have individual Dockerfiles in these subprojects for individual images. But I do know how to modify especially - the angular one to create jar  (mainly dockerfile does RUN npm run build -- --prod   , but gradle does dist/uiapp)

My dockerfile inside spring project (one of the module)

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine as build
WORKDIR /workspace/app

COPY . /workspace/app

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.gradle ./gradlew clean build -x test
RUN mkdir -p build/dependency && (cd build/dependency; jar -xf ../libs/*.jar)

WORKDIR /workspace/app/build/dependency

#RUN jar -xf ../*.jar

FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN addgroup -S demo && adduser -S demo -G demo
RUN mkdir -p /logs
RUN chown demo /logs

VOLUME /logs
USER demo
ARG DEPENDENCY=/workspace/app/build/dependency

COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-noverify","-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1","-cp","app:app/lib/*","-Dspring.main.lazy-initialization=true","-Dspring.profiles.active=cloud", "com.comp.some.SimpleApplication"]
```

How can I make a production docker image of all projects